# Proving isomorphism between tensor product and module.

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $A= \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Define $\phi: A^3 \to A^2$ by the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x & -y & 0 \\
    0 & x & -y 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and let define the module $M$ as the cokernel of $\phi$, that is, $$M=A^2/A^{\prime}$$ where $$A^{\prime}= \{ \begin{bmatrix}
    xp_1-yp_2  \\
    xp_2-yp_3
\end{bmatrix}:p_i \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y] \}.$$

Prove that $$M \otimes_{A}M \cong (A/(x,y))^4.$$

My attempt:

Since $(A/(x,y))^4= \mathbb{Q}^4$ we will try to find homomorphisms such that their compositions is the identity respectively. First, define $f: M \times M \to \mathbb{Q}^4$ by $(a,b)=(\overline{(q_1,q_2)},\overline{(q_3,q_4)}) \mapsto (c(q_1),c(q_2),c(q_3),c(q_4))$ where $c(q_i)$ denotes the constant term of $q_i$. I have managed to prove that this map is well defined and $A$-bilinear, hence by the universal property it exists a homomorphism $$f^{\prime}: M \otimes_{A} M \to \mathbb{Q}^4$$ given by $a \otimes b \mapsto c((q_1),c(q_2),c(q_3),c(q_4))$. Now I want to construct a homomorphism $g: \mathbb{Q}^4 \to M \otimes_{A} M$ such that $g \circ f^{\prime}$ and $f^{\prime} \circ g$ gives the identity respectively.  However I can't get the obvious choice for $g$ to work, namely I am not able to prove that $g \circ f^{\prime}$ is the identity, also I am struggling to prove that $g$ in fact is a well-defined homomorphism, I am really stuck.

Is this the right way to go? Or can I prove this in a much more simple manner?

Comment: Have you tried to show your map being injective and surjective?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Which one?

Comment: Since you say you have not really defined a $g$, I would try $f'$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I suspect it is not an isomorphism, do you think it is? In that case why?

Comment: Use this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418402/tensor-product-of-two-quotient-modules

Comment: @user26857 How can I use this? At first glance it looks like the result is a isomorphism by two tensor products. Can you clarify how I can use that result?

Comment: @user26857 I have looked closer to the result but I must say I am even more confused now, how can this result really be used in my case?

Comment: @Sodan I have no definite opinion on whether $f'$ is an isomorphism, but I suggested that you try to check whether it is injective and surjective, because if it is, then it is an iso. Surjectivity looks quite easy too. Why don't you try that route?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I tried! Surjectivity certainly holds, but the injectivity failed by a simple counterexample. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Aha. Can you show that simple counterexample?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I missed some details, did not seem to work. I am instead trying to prove that the kernel is trivial now. Getting late over here..

Comment: @Sodan I don't understand how the result can't be used in your case. We have that $A'$ is generated by three pairs, and $A'\otimes A^2$, respectively $A^2\otimes A'$ is a submodule of $A^2\otimes A^2=A^4$. Now keep the track of those generators an find $M\otimes M$ as a quotient of $A^4$ over a submodule with twelve generators. Then notice that this submodule is in fact $(Ax+Ay)^4$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you for the comment, would you mind posting an answer with some more details? Nice use of the theorem!

Comment: @Sodan I don't have much to add. The generators of the submodule of $A^4$ are $(x,0,0,0), (-y,x,0,0),(0,-y,0,0),\dots$. It's a good exercise to find them out. From these three we immediately notice that $Ax+Ay$ is on the first component, and so on.

Comment: @user26857 I do not understand your answer, I agree that you should post an answer with further details.